# Calculating CI's using bootstrapping on the holdout test dataset

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval

I’m trying to calculate 95% confidence intervals for the sensitivity and specificity of a decision model that I’m building.

I’ve split my dataset into 90/10 train and test sets. I’ve used the 90% train set to perform hyperparameter turning, and then used the optimal decision model selected from within the 90% train dataset to evaluate the 10% holdout dataset, which is fully independent, and not used in the hyperparameter tuning process.

My problem is, what's the best approach to obtain 95% confidence intervals for the training dataset? 
Should I bootstrap multiple subsets of the test data against the optimal model identified using hyperparameter tuning, and use those for the calculation? 
In example uses of bootstrapping that I found, different subsets of the train and test dataset are used for bootsrtapping. However, I don’t want to do that because I want my testing to be across a truly holdout (aka validation) dataset.

Comment: What are your sample sizes like? Why did you choose 90/10 instead of 75/25? What kind of a model is it in general? What parameter or summary statistic or you computing the confidence interval for?

Answer (score 0):

You train your model on the  90% train dataset and then you bootstrap on the validation set (10%) and classify. Then rank your results and CI will be given from 26th and 975th value.

Comment: See comment on other answer.

Comment: How do you know that is a confidence interval?

Answer (score 0):

Generate different 10% validation 90% training splits. Run model generation on each training set. Determine model performance on accompanying testing set. Determine confidence intervals from resulting vector of metrics. For more indepth look see https://www.sisostds.org/DesktopModules/Bring2mind/DMX/API/Entries/Download?Command=Core_Download&EntryId=36208&PortalId=0&TabId=105 $^\dagger$.

---

$\dagger$ link dead

Comment: Taking percentiles like that gives an interval of some kind, but I am not sure it is a confidence interval. Your linked paper does not mention cross validation, splitting, quantile, or percentile, which it should do if it is claiming that your idea is right. See this comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/100159/confidence-intervals-for-auc-using-cross-validation#comment193915_100159